# Getting Validation Accuracy of 99% with MNIST with less than 10000 parameters CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Given MNIST dataset in keras,the challenge is to develop a CNN neural net model with less than 10k parameters with 99% validation accuracy.

I tried making the model for the same but am getting accuracy as 98.71.

```
    def create_model():
        lay1=Conv2D(2,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu',padding='same')(inputs)
        lay1=Conv2D(2,kernel_size=(7,7),strides=(2,2),activation='relu',padding='same')(lay1)
        lay1=Conv2D(2,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu',padding='same')(lay1)
        lay1=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(7,7),strides=(2,2),padding='same')(lay1)
        lay2=Conv2D(4,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu',padding='same')(inputs)
        lay2=Conv2D(4,kernel_size=(7,7),strides=(2,2),activation='relu',padding='same')(lay2)
        lay2=Conv2D(4,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu',padding='same')(lay2)
        lay2=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(7,7),strides=(2,2),padding='same')(lay2)
        lay3=Conv2D(6,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu',padding='same')(inputs)
        lay3=Conv2D(6,kernel_size=(7,7),strides=(2,2),activation='relu',padding='same')(lay3)
        lay3=Conv2D(6,kernel_size=(1,1),activation='relu',padding='same')(lay3)
        lay3=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(7,7),strides=(2,2),padding='same')(lay3)
        fc=concatenate([lay1,lay2,lay3])
        fc=Flatten()(fc)
        fc=Dense(10,activation='relu')(fc)
        outputs=Dense(10,activation='softmax')(fc)
        model=Model(input=inputs,output=outputs)
        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

The total parameters coming are 8,862 and the batch size used for the above is 32 and the number of epochs are 10.

Can you please suggest ways to improve the model with the constraints on the number of parameters so that the validation accuracy is 99% or above?

Comment: Where you able to figure it  how to get accuracy more than 99%?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add another Conv/Pool block when reducing the kernel_size in the previous ones to 3 or 5 instead of 7. If research told us one thing recently is that deeper is (mostly) better.

Otherwise play with the hyperparameters (learning-rate, batch-size, ...) or augment the input data randomly. Batch- or Layer-Normalization have proven themselves very util lately (and they only introduce a handful of parameters).

Comment: I tried using Batch Normalization but now am getting less val accuracy with batch size used before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog post](https://myrtle.ai/how-to-train-your-resnet-8-bag-of-tricks/) which aims to train a CIFAR10 ResNet Classifier to reach 94% in few seconds. Although the goal is a liitle bit different, some tricks might be useful for you, such as CELU activation or label smoothing.

Comment: Got it. Thank you